# Sylius ProductBundle/ResourceBundle : how to enable HTML routing for products?

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I am trying to install some bundles provided by Sylius, but I don't want to install it fully. I began with ProductBundle. I'm using the v0.15.

After some struggle, I managed to create the schema in my database and enabled the router for the API endpoint of products. The code shown in the [ProductBundle documentation](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusProductBundle/installation.html) fails, but I managed to have my routes with this code:

```
app_product:
    resource: app_product
    type: sylius.api
```

I guess it's thanks to the `@SyliusResourceBundle/Routing/ApiLoader.php` class.
However, I would like to test the type `sylius.resource` described in the [ResourceBundle documentation](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusResourceBundle/configuration.html).

I can't find the definition of the loader - if there is one. And it collapses as soon as I try `php app/console debug:router` :

```
  [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]  
  Cannot load resource "alias: app.product                      
  ".
```

with the config:

```
app_product:
    resource: |
        alias: app.product
    type: sylius.resource
```

Can anyone point me to a correct configuration ?
Or could someone point me to a Loader or a similar tool that is defined somewhere in the code ?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understood how is that suppose to work. Sorry for answering to my own question, but if anyone actually come accross the same problem, it might help.

The documentation is actually up to date with the **dev** version of the project. If you still want to stick with some previous versions, you have to define your own routes as you would do in a standard Symfony application.
You can help yourself with `php app/console debug:container` to see what actually was created for your resource/product.

For french speaking developers, this talk helped me a lot :
http://fr.slideshare.net/ArnaudLanglade/dvelopper-avec-le-sylius-resourcebundle